Iterate over a list/range of strings while specifiying the custom start and stop
I have the following range in a string :
MyRange = 'IDxxx8:IDxxxC'

I would like to break it in the following way :
MyRange = 'IDxxx8, IDxxx9, IDxxxA, IDxxxB, IDxxxC'

The last character should go for from 1-9, and then A-Z. The predefine extended range would come from this list :
expected_range = [str(i) for i in range(0, 10)]
alphabet_range = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1)]
expected_range.extend(uppercase_alphabet_range)
# resulting in : expected_range = ['0','1','2',...,'8','9','A','B','C',..,'Y','Z']

I have the following code, but I dont know how to do a for loop over a custom range taking the resulting regex groups as Start and Stop. I'm not sure how go from here :
re.sub(r'(ID.{3})(.{1}):\1(.{1})$', (lambda m: ','.join(m.group(1) + str(i) for i in expected_range( m.group(2), m.group(3)) + 1), MyRange))

I know using the "expected_range()" in this way is wrong, but it's just to give an idea that I want to iterate over a custom range from a list.

expected_range[expected_range.index(m.group(2)) : expected_range.index(m.group(3)) + 1] perhaps?

Thanks Jason for the hint! this is very helpful indeed. I tried it with the given lambda function, and was getings an error, then I decided to break the lamda to a proper for loop and with your hint it works like a charm:)

You can do this without constructing the expected_range list, e.g:
import re


def my_expand(prefix, a, b):
    r = map(chr, range(ord(a), ord(b) + 1) if a < b else range(ord(a), ord(b) - 1, -1))
    return ", ".join(f"{prefix}{v}" for v in r if ("0" <= v <= "9") or ("A" <= v <= "Z"))


# MyRange = "IDxxxC:IDxxx8" # it works backwards too
MyRange = "IDxxx8:IDxxxC"

out = re.sub(
    r"(ID.{3})([0-9A-Z]):\1([0-9A-Z])",
    lambda x: my_expand(x[1], x[2], x[3]),
    MyRange,
)

print(out)

Prints:
IDxxx8, IDxxx9, IDxxxA, IDxxxB, IDxxxC


Or, you can do this how jasonharper suggested it in the comments, using str.index.

Thanks a lot Andrej! this a great solution too, and produces exactly what I need !
